# Textbook on QFT in curved space-time via path integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am looking for an introductory textbook on QFT in curved space-time via the path integral method. I want to understand the following:

- How to build a generic perturbative QFT in curved space-time
- Are there some specific difficulties with normalization
- How to derive observables / particle states in curved space-time
- The Unruh effect
- The Hawking radiation

I would appreciate if the author would use path integrals instead of the canonical formalism when possible. The reason for this is purely aesthetic.

Comment: There's a comprehensive book on path integrals by Kleinert, which discusses quantization on curved manifolds (chapter 10 of 'Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics [etc.]'). Wald's GR textbook also has a chapter on QFT in curved spacetime, and Carroll's textbook has a clear explanation of the Unruh effect.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110763/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest one of the (standard) books (though somehow old) on QFT  in curved spacetime,

- Quantum Fields in Curved Space (Birrel & Davies) 
  *Relates to path integral formalism, and covers a lot of topics in QFT on curved spacetime*
- Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime (Parker & Toms)
  *Uses DeWitt notation, a lot based on effective action derived from some path integral, very good book treating also black holes*
- [Quantum field theory in curved spacetime and black hole thermodynamics (R. Wald)]
  *Also standard text book, but I feel it might be only the third choice for you*

If you want to pursue afterwards you can have a look at DeWitt's work (however you have to get used to his style, afterwards its great)

- Quantum field theory in curved spacetime (DeWitt)

Summarizing I would say, for an answer to the first three issues Parker & Toms or DeWitt would be the best choice, however for a general introduction Birrel & Davies is quite nice and sufficient.