# Understanding Maxwell's equations in a non-intertial frame

Tags: electromagnetism, reference-frames, resource-recommendations, maxwell-equations

I'm trying to better understand "Maxwell's equations in a non-inertial frame" but a lot of the references I found (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3968) are too advanced. What are the suggested prerequisites? And are there any good textbooks/lectures/references to learn said prerequisites or this topic specifically?

Comment: Is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations_in_curved_spacetime) also too advanced?

Comment: Do you understand how Maxwell’s equations in an inertial frame can be written using 4D tensors like $F_{\mu\nu}$? If not, learn that first. Then learn differential geometry, including vierbeins, for generalizing  to an arbitrary frame.

Comment: Why did you choose the “quantum-mechanics” tag? Are you interested in classical EM in non-inertial frames or QED in non-inertial frames?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks so much for your responses. I think the wikipedia page is the correct scope of what I'm looking for although the tensor notation is too confusing for me. And yes, I'm interested in QED in non-inertial frames

Comment: @Math_Day QED in non-inertial frames is a topic within Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetimes. It does require a good understanding of Relativity in tensor notation

Comment: [Suggested reading for quantum field theory in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110763/168783)

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Thanks for the references! I originally didn't make the connection between what I was looking for and quantum field theory in curved space time so this is helpful!